# Unable to tap UIImage subview over MapKit view - Swift 4

Tags: iphone, swift, swift4

I've been having trouble interacting with an image that I've constrained to the upper left portion of my view. Everytime I try to tap on said images, my `#selector` method fails to invoke. I've had no difficulties tap-interacting in other view controllers where I don't have my map. Is it inherently impossible to tap `UIImage` objects over a `MapKit` map? I've done everything from creating delegates to checking for pesky nuances like setting my image object's `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

Answer (score -3):

So we've decided to place a button of the same size with the same placement as the image, but we set the color property of the button to isOpaque = true. This is functional, but very hacky. I'd still like to know if anyone has been able to crack this predicament of mine without resorting to such a roundabout way. If anyone has an answer, I'm all for self-improvement, so please don't hesitate to contribute to this thread! Thanks guys!

Comment: For the record, this isn't a *"thread"* in a forum - it's a Q&A site. You posted no code, was very vague in what you've tried, didn't tell us any specific constraints you have, shown no `#selector`... nothing. Then? You posted a "hacks" answer asking us not to not hesitate to contribute. Finally, a small and hopefully *not* critical mistake - `UIImage` is most certainly **not** tappable - but a `UIImageView` is. Please, post more details! (And my first thought of your true issue is wrong - you made sure that `UIImageView` is set to be intractive.